# ClusterIP with externalIPs - can't be accessed from outside the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In the past I've tried `NodePort` service and if I add a firewall rule to the corresponding Node, it works like a charm:

```
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30000
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
```

I can access my service from outside and long as the node has an external IP(which it does by default in GKE).
However, the service can only be assigned to 30000+ range ports, which is not very convenient.
By the way, the Service looks as follows:

```
 kubectl get service -o=wide
NAME                     TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE   SELECTOR
web-engine-service   NodePort   10.43.244.110   <none>        80:30000/TCP   11m   app=web-engine-pod
```

Recently, I've come across a different configuration option that is documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips).
I've tried is as it seems quite promising and should allow to expose my service on any port I want.
The configuration is as follows:

```
  ports:
    - name: web-port
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
  externalIPs:
    - 35.198.163.215
```

After the service updated, I can see that External IP is indeed assigned to it:

```
$ kubectl get service -o=wide
NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
web-engine-service   ClusterIP   10.43.244.110   35.198.163.215   80/TCP    19m   app=web-engine-pod
```

(where `35.198.163.215` - Node's external IP in GKE)

And yet, my app is not available on the Node's IP, unlike in the first scenario(I did add firewall rules for all ports I'm working with including `80`, `5000`, `30000`).

What's the point of `externalIPs` configuration then? What does it actually do?

**Note:** I'm creating a demo project, so please don't tell me about `LoabBalancer` type, I'm well aware of that and will get to that a bit later.

Comment: does your external IPs route to one or more cluster nodes? All Traffic that ingresses into the cluster with the external IP (as destination IP), on the Service port, will be routed to one of the Service endpoints.

Comment: Yes, it does and in NodePort scenario it's the same node with the same IP and everything works.

Comment: What is the error you get when trying to hit that IP? Can you prove that you have routes from that IP to your Node(s)?

Comment: The proof is that it works via both local curl and directly in the browser for the same IP when I use NodePort for the same Node.

Comment: Are you saying that you specified a Node's IP as the externalIP? I can't see that detail in the question.

Comment: Yes, updated my question. That's important detail, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give you more insight on:

- How you can manage to make it work.
- Why it's not working in your example.
- More information about exposing traffic on `GKE`.

---

#### How you can manage to make it work?

You will need to enter **internal IP** of your node/nodes to the service definition where `externalIP` resides.

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-external
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
    version: 2.0.0
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80 # port to send the traffic to
      targetPort: 50001 # port that pod responds to 
  externalIPs:
    - 10.156.0.47
    - 10.156.0.48
    - 10.156.0.49
```

---

#### Why it's not working in your example?

I've prepared an example to show you why it doesn't work.

Assuming that you have:

- VM in GCP with:

  - any operating system that allows to run `tcpdump`
  - internal IP of: `10.156.0.51`
  - external IP of: `35.246.207.189`
  - allowed the traffic to enter on port: `1111` to this VM

You can run below command **(on VM)** to capture the traffic coming to the port: `1111`:

- `$ tcpdump port 1111 -nnvvS`

> - -nnvvS - don't resolve DNS or Port names, be more verbose when printing info, print the absolute sequence numbers

You will need to send a request to external IP: `35.246.207.189` of your VM with a port of: `1111`

- `$ curl 35.246.207.189:1111`

You will get a connection refused message but the packet will be captured. You will get an output similar to this:

```sh
tcpdump: listening on ens4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:04:25.704299 IP OMMITED 
    YOUR_IP > 10.156.0.51.1111: Flags [S], cksum 0xd9a8 (correct), seq 585328262, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 1282380791 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:04:25.704337 IP OMMITED
    10.156.0.51.1111 > YOUR_IP: Flags [R.], cksum 0x32e3 (correct), seq 0, ack 585328263, win 0, length 0
```

By that example you can see the destination IP address for your packet coming to the VM. As shown above it's the **internal IP** of your VM and not external. That's why putting external IP in your `YAML` definition is not working.

> This example also works on `GKE`. For simplicity purposes you can create a `GKE` cluster with Ubuntu as base image and do the same as shown above.

You can read more about IP addresses by following link below:

- *[Cloud.google.com: VPC: Docs: IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/ip-addresses)*

---

#### More about exposing traffic on `GKE`

> What's the point of  `externalIPs`  configuration then? What does it actually do?

In simple terms it will allow the traffic to enter your cluster. Request sent to your cluster will need to have destination IP the same as in the `externalIP` parameter in your service definition to be routed to the corresponding service.

This method requires you to track the IP addresses of your nodes and could be prone to issues when the IP address of your node will not be available (nodes autoscaling for example).

I recommend you to expose your services/applications by following official `GKE` documentation:

- [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Exposing apps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps)

As mentioned before, `LoadBalancer` type of service will automatically take into consideration changes that were made to the cluster. Things like autoscaling which increase/decrease count of your nodes. With the service shown above (with `externalIP`) this would require manual changes.

Please let me know if you have any questions to that.

Comment: Thanks Dawid. What you wrote makes a lot of sense, but it's still not the answer to what I wanted to figure out. I really don't understand the point of externalIPs configuration option. I do understand it's not a reliable way to expose services, even if it were possible. I do use HTTPs LoadBalancer in real workloads.

Comment: The point of it is the same as in the documentation. If you have facilities that are sending the traffic to your cluster with "some" IP, you can get this traffic which arrives to your cluster with "some"(`destination IP`) to be sent to the svc of your choosing. You can read more about by following this link: https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-external-ip-service-type-5e5e9ad62fcd .

Comment: Interesting; for me, setting the `externalIPs` to the actual external ip for my node worked for a `NodePort`, even when the port was set to `80`, `81`, etc. (to be clear, exposing on port 80 only worked once I had set the `externalIPs` value)

Answer (score 1):

In the [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#servicespec-v1-core), `externalIPs` is documented as (emphasis mine):

> externalIPs is a list of IP addresses for which nodes in the cluster will also accept traffic for this service. **These IPs are not managed by Kubernetes. The user is responsible for ensuring that traffic arrives at a node with this IP.** A common example is external load-balancers that are not part of the Kubernetes system.

So you can put any IP address you want there, and it will show up in `kubectl get service` output, but it doesn't mean the cluster will actually accept traffic there.

To accept inbound traffic from outside the cluster, you need a minimum of a NodePort service; in a cloud environment a LoadBalancer service or an Ingress is a more common setup.  You can't really short-cut around these.  Conversely, a LoadBalancer isn't especially advanced or difficult, just change `type: LoadBalancer` in the configuration you already show and GKE will create the endpoint for you.  The [GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer) has a more complete example.

("Inside the cluster" and "outside the cluster" are different networks, and like other NAT setups pods can generally make outbound calls but you need specific setup to accept inbound calls.  That's what a NodePort service does, and in the standard setup a LoadBalancer service builds on top of that.)

Comment: I don't see how that piece of documentation, which is pretty similar to the one I provided, contradicts with what I'm trying to accomplish. It's my responsibility and I made sure to provide an IP that I know for sure is external and available from outside. Even this sentence "A common example is external load-balancers that are not part of the Kubernetes system" - basically means that it should be accessible as long as I configured networking outside kubernetes properly.

Comment: If I make a TCP connection to `35.198.163.215:80`, what forwards it to the relevant pods?  The key point of that documentation fragment is that Kubernetes doesn't do this, it depends on something else to do that forwarding.

Comment: Ok, in that case, if service is not doing anything with it, what's the point of specifying it? It seems that it is, as I read in some other thread, for "documentation purpose".

Comment: That's about right.  A controller could set it.  The same thing happens for LoadBalancer services: you can specify the address yourself, but usually a controller will set it, and it's something more for an administrator to read back out.